# How to pass form user input through to the function which runs on form submit and create a cookie with the name of the users input?

Tags: javascript, cookies

The code below successfully creates the cookie with the string value 'XinputX'. However I am looking for it to be the value of the users input.

I also need to go to another page with the same click, where would I put that action if the onSubmit is already being used to set the cookie?

```js
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="d-flex mx-auto mt-5 mb-5">
      Hello and welcome to the quiz.
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex mx-auto mb-5">

      <form onsubmit="createCookie('first_cookie','XinputX',7)">

        Enter name:
        <input type="text">

        <input type="submit">

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mx-auto">

      <button type="button" id="nextQuestion" class="btn btn-primary d-flex mx-auto mt-2">Lets go!</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "go somewhere else" can be done by adding an action or in script.
2. You need to cancel the submit if you do not want to use the action

I have replaced the cookie code with console.log because SO does not allow to set cookies. Just remove the // when you upload

I have also named the field and given the form an ID

```js
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else var expires = "";
  // document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
  console.log("cookie",name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/")
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name, "", -1);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission, remove this if you add an action to the form
    createCookie('first_cookie', this.textField.value,7);
    // if you do not want to use the action attribute of the form you can do this:
    // window.location="somewhereelse.html"; 
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex mx-auto mt-5 mb-5">
      Hello and welcome to the quiz.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex mx-auto mb-5">
      <form id="myForm">
        Enter name:
        <input name="textField" type="text">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mx-auto">
      <button type="button" id="nextQuestion" class="btn btn-primary d-flex mx-auto mt-2">Lets go!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JakeS I added a comment to the submit handler